# VideoView Activity Malfunctions when Intent is called from current Activity's View

Tags: android

I have my main Activity, it starts with a custom SurfaceView called DrawView being set by setContentView.  The Main Activity (Draw) has the following method within it

```
public void launchCutScene(int scene) {     
    Intent intent = new Intent(Draw.this, CutScene.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);  
}
```

if I call this method directly after setContentView the new Activity CutScene loads properly.  CutScene is as follows

```
public class CutScene extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener{
String pathToFile = "";
VideoView videoPlayer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pathToFile = "EM Math/" + "st.mp4";

        setContentView(R.layout.main);   
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        videoPlayer = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);  
        videoPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        videoPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        videoPlayer.setKeepScreenOn(true);    
        videoPlayer.setVideoPath(root + "/" + pathToFile);  
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer vp) {             
       videoPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer  mp) {
       finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev){   
       if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
          if(videoPlayer.isPlaying()){
            videoPlayer.pause();
          } else {
                   videoPlayer.start();
          }
          return true;      
       } else {
          return false;
       }
    }
}
```

However, if within DrawView I call draw.launchCutScene(0) then the activity still comes up, but the video glitches, it either stays as a black screen and you have to press back to make the activity crash, in which case it will bring up the first activity.  Or it will play the sound only but multiple times and un-synced.  Either way after it crashes if a launchCutScene call is done again within the DrawView class the video now works fine.

Why is this happening? does anybody understand what I need to do?

Comment: Please note I have discovered this error might just be happening when the launchCutScene method is called from within my games main thread (this happens on the drawview). Not sure if that helps with solution, I am currently trying to stop my thread, then call up the cutscene then start thread again once cutscene activity is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Finely fixed the error!

All I had to do was set my threads runnable boolean to false, then call the activity.  Once activity closes my program reinitiates the thread, and everything work hunkydorry now!!!!...  So if your getting this Video Bug with your Video Views it's probably because you are running a thread in the background!